# Weighted Interval Scheduling using recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion

The Weighted Interval Scheduling problem is this: Given a set of weighted intervals, choose a set of non-overlapping intervals such that the total weight is maximal.
A weighted interval x can be represented by a triple x = (s, f, v),
where
s=start time of x, f=finish time of x, v=weight or value of x￼
These weighted intervals can be represented by the triples
(0,3,3) (1,4,2) (0,5,4) (3,6,1) (4,7,2) (3,9,5) (5,10,2) (8,10,1)
Write a program to compute a solution to the Weighted Interval Scheduling problem.
Here is a picture of the graph:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy0v8.jpg

The program should print out the value of the total weight of the optimum
solution and the indices of the selected intervals. In the above case, the output
would be something like (this output is NOT correct)
     Optimum value: 7
     Interval Sequence: 2 5
The program MUST use recursion.

The algorithm for computing the optimum value is:
Input: n, s1,...,sn , f1,...,fn , v1,...,vn

Sort jobs by finish times so that f1 > f2 >... > fn.
Compute p(1), p(2), ..., p(n)
Where p(j) = largest index i < j such that job i is compatible with j.

```
for j = 1 to n
   M[j] = empty <-- solution table
M[j] = 0

M-Compute-Opt(j) {
   if (M[j] is empty)
      M[j] = max(wj + M-Compute-Opt(p(j)), M-Compute-Opt(j-1))
   return M[j]
}
```

I have created a class Job that has 3 ints: start, finish, and weight.
I have an array of type job with each of the different intervals in each spot of the size 8 array.
Question:
How do I compute p for each job interval?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem that can be solved with Dynamic Programming.

For each i from 1 to n, save the max weights you can schedule, as well as the ending date of the last intervals used for these weights. You only store possible weights that are interesting. For instance intervals 1+4 (w=4) are less interesting than interval 3 (w=4), since the latter ends before the former and the total weight is the same.

The trick in Dynamic Programming is to move one item by one item, from 1 to n. At each step, figure out if the new data available at that step leads to a better answer, a different possible answer, or a worse answer. Only better and different answers need to be saved before moving to the next step.

```
date    max weight  last interval
1       0           0
2       0           0
3       3           1
4       3           1
5       3 or 4      1 or 3 
6       4           3
7       4 or 5      3 or 5
8       4 or 5      3 or 5
9       5 or 8      5 or 6 
10      last step is for you, if I did not make mistakes in other rounds...
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help.....

```
public static int p(int index){
    for(int i=(index-1); i >=0; i--){
        if(f[i] <= s[index-1])  return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```